# Using egrep to search for IP address by octets from a shell variable

Tags: bash, scripting, ip-address, iptables, grep

I'm writing a BASH script that outputs `iptables -L -n` and searches for the existence of an IP address.   I'm stuck with how to use this with *egrep*.  Roughly:

```
CHECK=$(iptables -L -n | egrep $the_string)
```

which "looks" like it would work, but it doesn't have an end delimiter `$` so it would match:

`25.24.244`
and
`25.24.24`

When I really just need to match for `25.24.24` only.

I tried escaping this but the `$` creates issues with the regular expression.

At least this is the only means I've found to search for the IP in the *iptables* system.  It doesn't appear to have any query mechanism itself (puzzling).

I am probably missing something very simple here, and just need a pointer or two :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should *backslash* the `.` : this means *any character* in regex...

```
iptables -L -n | grep "25\.24\.24$"
```

(no need `egrep` there)

Answer (score 0):

The `$` at the end of the regular expression works as expected:

```
the_ip=25.24.24
the_string=$(echo $the_ip | sed 's/\./\\\./g')
iptables -L -n | egrep "$the_string$"
```